# I'm trying to change the sandbox host used by the SSRS fetchdatasource

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-365

I'm not a CRM guy. I'm a SQL server / C# / general problem solver guy.

I'm trying to help one of our IT teams migrate to CRM 365. They are having issues with reports.

When I look at the report server log, I see that the relevant error seems to be:

`Could not connect to net.tcp://<crmappserver>/CrmSandboxSdkListener-w3wp`

We have four CRM application servers. Two of them have the "CRM sandbox listener", and two do not.  I don't know what the sandbox listener is or does, but that probably doesn't matter. What *does* matter is that the "crmappserver" in the URL is one of the two hosts *without* the sandbox listener installed. So, no surprise that it can't connect!

I relayed this information to the CRM team, but nobody in the team knows how to configure the fetch data source to use a particular host.

There's nothing in the data connector setup that allows me to enter that information: all I can enter is the SQL Server. So, I deduce that this information must be in the CRM configuration database somewhere, so I suggested that the team look through the administrative side of the CRM web user interface to see what they could find. But apparently the can find nowhere to configure this value.

How can we configure the CRM SSRS Fetch data source to point to host 3 instead of host 1 when it goes looking for the CRMSandboxSdkListener worker process?

Update from the CRM development team follows:

According to the CRM team, the report in question was originally created through the CRM application via the report wizard (probably in CRM 2011). As such, this report was always configured to use a fetch data source. The report works in CRM 2011, but the CRM 365 (on premise) platform is hosted on a different set of application servers.

In the CRM 365 installation the report is *not* pointing to one of the old 2011 hosts, which is good. Somehow during migration is has detected that the URL had to be updated from the old 2011 host to one of the four new 365 hosts. However, the problem remains that the 365 sandbox listener host referenced by the fetch data source is not one of the two hosts which is actually running that service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are currently on-Premise of Dynamics 365 (crm). You had your reports previously built with Sql data source (I believe).
Dynamics crm has changed the way Reports are been created in CRM. CRM does need FetchXMl as data source and not Sql.

Now you wish to change connection string/url so that it points to correct dynamics instance.

I would refer you to below link,This link shows how to create a SSRS report.
What is important in your case is Installing Microsoft dynamics 365 Reporting extension.Once you have this installed you would be have under Data source Type (Fetchxml) and then giving correct connection string will get you further.

Here is the Link:http://mastermindtechies.com/blogs/creating-ssrs-report-dynamics-365-online/

Comment: Thank you, your answer is helpful and I have upvoted it. As it turns out I have received more information from the CRM development team, and am about to update my question with that new information.

Comment: Apparently only one report was created via the CRM wizard, so the CRM team have simply redone that report in the new environment, which resolves the issue. However, I expect your approach also would have worked, so I have marked it as an answer.